# MeteorJS & Collection2. How to create Schema with data of type 'Time'?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

Hi I'm trying to create a MongoDB Collection with a Collection2 schema connected to an Autoform (specifically a Quickform if possible) That allows me to store a time and date, not just a date.

For a date, the JSON validation is `type: Date,` - is there a `type: Time`?

Or another way to insert a date/time picker into an autoform and save it to a Collection2 Schema Collection?

Thanks for any help or hints pointing to similar problems.

Comment: You want `Date` as it stores in less space and is a lot more useful than an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was just being stupid.

```
type: Date
```

is still correct as Blakes Seven 7 pointed out (thanks).

There is a package called aldeed:autoform-bs-datetimepicker which you need to add to your Meteor app to include the datetime picker in your quickform/autoform.

a sample schema which works is then:

```
  {
  typeTest: {
    type: Date,
    optional: true,
    autoform: {
      afFieldInput: {
        type: "bootstrap-datetimepicker"
      }
    }
  }
}
```